# customising announcement list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, web-parts

I am trying to add a customised  announcement list to the main page of my SharePoint site on this list, there will be 7 columns on the list but the challenge i'm having now is how to  only display 3 out of the 7 columns on the site and the other columns will only be displayed when user clicks on add new announcement or clicks on the list itself. Please can anyone give me an idea of how to achieve this.

E.g: Assuming i customised an announcement list to have column:  management, operations, Assets, Finance,HR,QHSE and Technical and added it on my SharePoint page via web-part, How can i make it to only display 3 of the 7 columns like  management, operations, Assets while other columns will only be seen whenever users click on the add new announcement or go directly to the list itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For displaying only 3 columns, create a view and set it in the webpart options.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new view of a SharePoint list, it essentially creates a new .aspx page with the view customized per your definition.  This can be done for standard views easily from the SharePoint list's web interface.  This is the suggestion from Le_Freddo and should work for creating custom views but not for creating custom edit pages.

For that I believe you need to use SharePoint Designer.  Open the site in SharePoint Designer then locate the list you're working on under 'Lists' in the 'FolderList'.  You'll see 4 pages, AllItems, DispForm, EditForm, and NewForm.  Make a copy of the EditForm (before you modify it), then open the EditForm to make your changes to it.  You can add or remove fields from the page.  In this way you can customize the Edit form to show all fields or only a subset.

You can also use this method to customize the other views (removing columns you don't want users to see).

When you're done, you can direct your List to use the new pages or define which page to use for each operation (View-All, Display, Edit, Create New) by setting the List's properties (right click the list in the Folder View, select Properties, then the 'Supporting Files' tab will have links to the pages configured for these actions).

Good luck...